# Shiny dateRangeInput - extract month and year from user input

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to know if it is possible to extract month and year into separate variables from dateRangeInput after user input.

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Time Series forecasting with arima+stl"),
    sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                 label = paste('Date range selection'),
                 start = "2010-01-01",
                 end   = "2012-12-31", 
                 min = "2010-01-01",
                 max = "2012-12-31",
                 separator = " - ", 
                 weekstart = 1
   ),
   actionButton("Go", "Go!")
),

)
))
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(

    function(input, output, session){

       forecast <- eventReactive(input$Go, {

          })

})
```

From what I have read on this subject so far I only know how to extract the entire date from user input. In the above code is there a way for me to use a variable which contains the start and end month that which is obtained from dateRangeInput in server.ui? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: format(input$dateRange[1], "%Y") should give you the year. %m should give you month. dateRange[1] has start date, dateRante[2] has end date.

Comment: It worked! Thank you:)